# How can I resolve multiple version incompatibilities in npm at the same time?

Tags: angularjs, npm-install, yarnpkg, npm-scripts, npm-start

I want to run angular locally and once I run `npm install` in my local Clone I'd get

```
warning Resolution field "https-proxy-agent@5.0.1" is incompatible with requested 
version "https-proxy-agent@5.0.0"
warning Resolution field "saucelabs@7.1.3" is incompatible with requested version 
"saucelabs@^1.5.0"
warning Resolution field "https-proxy-agent@5.0.1" is incompatible with requested 
version "https-proxy-agent@^2.2.1"
warning Resolution field "https-proxy-agent@5.0.1" is incompatible with requested 
version "https-proxy-agent@5.0.0"
warning Resolution field "saucelabs@7.1.3" is incompatible with requested version 
"saucelabs@^4.6.3"
warning Resolution field "https-proxy-agent@5.0.1" is incompatible with requested 
version 
"https-proxy-agent@^4.0.0"
[3/5] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-4.7.1- 
linux.tar.gz: Request failed \"403 Forbidden\"".
```

As you can see there are multiple version incompatibilities at the same time. How can I resolve this?

I tried to install specific versions but after running `yarn install` in my local angular directory I still get the same errors for these incompatibilities.
I really appreciate your help with this issue.